# Doctrine inherit entity

Tags: inheritance, doctrine

**Edit: This example is fully working :-) Mea culpa**

I need inherit entity:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "User", "worker" = "Worker", "customer" =     "Customer"})
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
   }
```

And child enity:

```
 /**
  * Worker
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="worker")
  * @ORM\Entity
  */
 class Worker extends User
 { 
 }
```

And there is part of my database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `worker` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE `worker`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Worker_User` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON     DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

What am I doing wrong? When I try to work with user entity (which is not abstract!) I get error:
    Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException

```
An exception occurred while executing 
'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.surname AS surname3, 
t0.email AS email4, t0.password AS password5, t0.phone AS phone6, 
t0.www AS www7, t0.skype AS skype8, t0.active AS active9, 
t0.datetime AS datetime10, t0.role_id AS role_id11, 
t0.company_id AS company_id12, t0.type, t13.salary AS salary14, 
t13.hourSalary AS hourSalary15, t13.parent AS parent16, t13.userGroup_id AS userGroup_id17 
FROM user t0 
LEFT JOIN worker t13 ON t0.id = t13.id 
LEFT JOIN customer t18 ON t0.id = t18.id 
WHERE t0.email = ? LIMIT 1' 
with params {"1":"info@ondrej-sejvl.cz"}: 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't13.id' in 'on clause'
```

Why is t13.id columng unknown.. It is in my DB

Comment: I am so sorry :-) this example is fully working, I just forget to change database parameter, so I was working with different database..